# firestore security rules at request.auth.uid == id

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I tried to set up basic security rules and have stored uid returned from request.auth in my document as document id but when setting up the rules

`match /users/{id} 
allow read,write: if request.auth.uid == id`

it won't allow. Why is that?
Thanks in advance.
[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to specify a proper document name and not an alias like `/users/{id}`.
2. You have to specify the uid of the requester, identical to the document name according to your rule

Sum up, try:

Location= `/users/dummyid`

uid= `dummyid`

Comment: as per the documentation the curly braces supposed to represent the document id ? I tried the following and it worked but it is strange the curly brace didn't ?                     
   `match /users/{userId} {
     allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.userId
     allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }`